# Mysql if record count greater than X, then run this?

Tags: mysql

I am running the following code from a Windows batch file to remove records that are no longer needed from several MySql tables.

```
DELETE FROM TableA
WHERE SystemID NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM MasterTable)  ;

DELETE FROM TableB
WHERE SystemID NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM MasterTable)
```

Before that code runs there is an import of the batch of data into the MasterTable. Everything works fine as long as nothing goes wrong with the import to the MasterTable. What can I put before the above code that would check the record count of MasterTable and if it is greater than X then run the sql above?

Comment: Mysql does not support if statements. You have to write an if statement with your programming language of choice, that runs a mysql command once a row count is greater than x.

Comment: You can easily do this in your application layer. If you're stuck doing it 100% in MySQL then you have to define a stored procedure.

Comment: *Before that code runs there is an import of the batch of data into the MasterTable.* I.e. "import then delete". *What can I put before the above code that would check the record count of MasterTable and if it is greater than X then run the sql above?* Do you want to have "delete then import then delete"?

Comment: How often the importing process is performed? Maybe it is safe to realize old values deletion as an event procedure (delete old rows by schedule)?

Comment: The import into MasterTable is done once each day. The MasterTable is truncated and all current data is imported into it. Then the Delete occurs on tables A and B for data lines in which the systemId is not in the MasterTable.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the IF test. What's wrong with simply running (a more efficient version of) these queries daily?

Comment: What is your suggestion on making them more efficient? Keep in mind I'm going for foolproof so TableA and TableB do not have all records deleted.